# Is code motion permitted in presence of atomic memory accesses?

Tags: c++11, atomic, compiler-optimization

Looking at the following example,

```
#include <atomic>

extern std::atomic<int> TheVal;
extern std::atomic<bool> Ready;
int Unrelated;

void test() {
  for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    Unrelated = 42; // A loop-invariant store
    if (Ready.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) continue;
    TheVal.store(i, std::memory_order_release);
    Ready.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
  }
}
```

Is the compiler allowed to move the store to 'Unrelated' out of the loop such that test() would be similar to the following?

```
void test() {
  Unrelated = 42; // Move the loop-invariant store here
  for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    if (Ready.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) continue;
    TheVal.store(i, std::memory_order_release);
    Ready.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
  }
}
```

If the variables 'Ready' and 'TheVal' were not atomic then this optimization would be surely safe, but does their atomicity prevent this optimization?

Comment: I believe the optimization is safe under as-if rule. I don't see how a race-free program could be able to tell the difference. If there's another thread that also writes to `Unrelated`, then there's a data race. If no other thread writes to `Unrelated`, then it doesn't matter whether it's set once or multiple times.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes i tend to think the same, but am wondering if the standard has any sections specifying if this is allowed

Comment: The standard doesn't explicitly specify all possible optimizations. Instead, the standard promulgates the as-if rule: "**[intro.execution]/1** The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This International Standard places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below."

Comment: Under this rule, an optimization is valid iff the resulting program produces the same observable behavior as a program without the optimization (or more generally, if the optimization produces one of the allowable observable behaviors). Another way to look at the rule: an optimization if valid iff no conforming program can detect whether or not it has in fact been applied.